# Google Service account usage suddenly drops

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

We've been seing some sudden strange behaviour of our service account in Google Cloud console these past few days. We're using this service account to authenticate our API with Firebase SDK - and without any warnings the usage of this account just drops to zero (see attached screenshot).

There are no warnings from Firebase SDK telling us that the service account is no longer valid, and in fact the service account is stated as "active" in the cloud console. From Firebase SDK logs we're actually seing the read/writes be completed, but they are not actual performed when viewing the data in Firebase console, which is why I expect the problem to be within the service account.

The temporarily solution has been to create a new service account and upload the associated key to our API. Then it starts working again without any additional actions required, but suddenly the usage drops to zero after 12hours++.

There are no alarms in Google Cloud Console and billing is activated with status OK.

Since the Firebase logs tells us "everything is OK", and Google Cloud console does not show any warnings, I don't understand where the problem might be. Anyone experienced something similar, and could point me in the right direction? Any help is much appreciated!

[Metric graph of service account usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4zQC.png)

Comment: I think you have a "behavior" problem with monitoring, and I do not know of a problem or solution. Review the logs for your service to see if there are authorization failures. If there are none, you do not have a problem that "you" can solve. Google will need to review the monitoring features. Open a support ticket or create an incident here: https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers